# Unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml. (font)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use a custom font in flutter. I've placed the font in a "fonts" folder in my root directory, at the same level as my pubspec.yaml file

[image]

I've also added the font to my pubspec.yaml using the format in the documentation. Full file:

```
name: app_name
description: app_description

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter




  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  rxdart: ^0.22.1+1
  intl: ^0.15.7



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.2"
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter




flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: /fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf


flutter_icons:
  ios: true
  android: true
  image_path_ios: "lib/res/launcher/ic_launcher_iphone.png"
  image_path_android: "lib/res/launcher/ic_launcher.png"
```

I'm still getting the above error

`Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf".`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the leading `/`. `asset: /fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf` -> `asset: fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf`

Make sure your fonts folder is in the top folder of your project.